# Issue with an abbreviation RDT that affects close reasons for questions

Tags: discussion, moderation, close-reasons

First, this is about providing accurate close reasons for questions, that are most likely off-topic anyways. If you don't think it is relevant, you can ignore the rest of the text.

First thing some people think when heaaring this abbreviation is: RDT refers to [real data transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Data_Transport). I don't know anything about it, besides that it is a protocol to transport multimedia. And as such, I would assume, that the one thing it does not do is any form of ARQ (i.e., acks, timeouts and retransmissions).

So far there were at least two questions closed, since "they refer to protocol above OSI layer 4 and are off-topic".

Now, this particular **close reason is incorrect**. The problem is that Kurose and Ross in their book, *in their infinite wisdom*™ decided to use the abbreviation RDT for *reliable data transport*, and use this term to refer to what I believe *everyone else calls ARQ*. Apparently there are RDT 1.0, 2.0, etc which refer to Stop-and-Wait, Alternate Bit Protocol, Go-Back-N, and so on. AFAIK Kurose and Ross's book is still recommended by almost all college networking course. So, **people ask questions about ARQ and call them RDT.**

Now, I don't quite get the policy about questions about ARQ. Homework is offtopic (so such questions are clearly out). However, *design or theory of protocols used to operate a network* is ontopic, and, understanding basic ARQs belong to theory of any reliable protocol **operating either layer 2 or layer 4**. On the other hand, since it is clearly basic building blocks theory, not protocols themeselves, redirecting such questions to e.g., [Computer Science CE](https://cs.stackexchange.com) under tag [computer-networks] is probably a better option.

**P.S.** And also I would like to point out, that texts of both questions did mention basic ARQ mechanisms. So it absolutely obvious that the questions were about an ARQ mechanism and definitelly not about a *multimedia* transport protocol. So providing accurate close reason was no problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. Questions about L1-L4 protocol theory are legitimate, so ARQ questions are basically on topic, unless convoluted by overly academic or certification-oriented ideas.

Since Kurose and Ross sometimes stray in that direction, like you have indicated, I'd tend to put those questions in that corner. Also, if the OP doesn't provide sufficient context for us to make sense of their question, it's quickly becoming off-topic for being ambiguous and unclear.

However, you're making an excellent point here and we should keep that problem in mind - and ask the OP what the question is about exactly before closing it.

Comment: the issue is - there was sufficient context. One of the questions asked about behavior of Go-Back-N and it was written in the text. And another one wrote what this abbreviation means (i.e. words "reliable data transfer") in the text.

Comment: ARQ is _not_ used in a "_professionally managed network_"

Comment: @RonMaupin TCP uses *go-back-n ARQ* and optionally *selective repeat ARQ*.

Comment: We had problems in the past with questions about the ARQ theory conflicting with something an instructor thought, and it caused problems. There is no standard to which we can point to say that ARQ is this way or that way. TCP has standards to which we can point, but it sometimes differs from the academic ARQ. I remember a question that was answered for ARQ with the way TCP works, and it caused dissension and arguments.

Comment: @RonMaupin Quite true - that's what I was referring to with *convoluted by overly academic or certification-oriented ideas* above.

Comment: @RonMaupin every answer to every question can conflict with "something that instructor said". Sometimes standards are unclear and can be interpreted in different ways. Sometimes vendors include non-standard features, and there are no descriptions.

Comment: and what is this then? https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=arq

Comment: @RonMaupin Also, ARQs, in some form, are used in most wireless networks. And some of wireless networks are professionally managed.

Comment: That is why we do not answer questions about purely academic protocols for which there is no standard, only real protocols for which there is a standard to which we can refer. Basically, questions about ARQ that do not refer to a real protocol, e.g. how does TCP implement ARQ?,  are no longer on-topic because they are purely theoretical with no backing standard, and are not used in a business network.

Comment: @RonMaupin ok, so we are not answering questions about EIGRP either?

Comment: Cisco has a standard for EIGRP. There are Cisco documents to which we can point for specifics of a question.

Comment: @RonMaupin and Kurose/Ross is a well known textbook that can be pointed to as well. And there are definitelly a couple others that can be pointed to.

Comment: @RonMaupin and in any case, closing the question because it is about `protocols above OSI layer-4` is not the accurate close reason.

Comment: @RonMaupin let's close them as educational and point to cs.stackexchange.com, no problem. But write this in close reason, not something that does not make sense.

Comment: I have not closed any question about ARQ for being above OSI layer-4. RDT is a protocol above OSI layer-4. Also, textbooks are not standards, and they often have errors. The real point of requiring a protocol to have a standard to which one can point, and to be used in a business network, is to reduce flame wars. Also, the professional engineers here objected to such academic questions.

Comment: @RonMaupin I am glad that noone actually read what I wrote. So I will repeat the summary. Kurose/Ross had a great idea to call ARQ **reliable data transfer**, or **RDT**. These questions had nothing to do with the RDT protocol that you mentioned.

Comment: I read what you wrote, but RDT is an established protocol that is above OSI layer-4, regardless of what is written in a textbook. Absent any clarifying information, references to RDT are assumed to be the established protocol that started as a proprietary protocol (about which we have gotten questions in the past), but it is now maintained by a different group.

Comment: @RonMaupin a question, whose text is mentioning Go-Back-N and ACKs cannot be about the established RDT protocol (for multimedia). It just cant.  Multimedia protocols do not do retransmissions.

Comment: The close reason is exactly the same: "_NE is a site for to ask and provide answers about professionally managed networks in a business environment. Your question falls outside the areas our community decided are on topic. Please visit the help center for more details. If you disagree with this closure, please ask on Network Engineering Meta._"

Comment: Zac can deal with this ... however he seems appropriate

Comment: Well, I'm fine with refining the next question so we can better see whether it's on or off topic. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> First, this is about providing accurate close reasons for questions,
> that are most likely off-topic anyways.

There are only a few close reasons:

[image]

What do you think should be the close reason for any type of question to which you refer? What you are mentioning falls into the second one that covers a wide variety of off-topic questions, and the reason given the OP for that is listed in the box above the question as:

> NE is a site for to ask and provide answers about professionally
> managed networks in a business environment. Your question falls
> outside the areas our community decided are on topic. Please visit the
> help center for more details. If you disagree with this closure,
> please ask on Network Engineering Meta.

I do not see where that is an inaccurate close reason.

---

> Now, I don't quite get the policy about questions about ARQ. Homework
> is offtopic (so such questions are clearly out). However, design or
> theory of protocols used to operate a network is ontopic, and,
> understanding basic ARQs belong to theory of any reliable protocol
> operating either layer 2 or layer 4. On the other hand, since it is
> clearly basic building blocks theory, not protocols themeselves,
> redirecting such questions to e.g., Computer Science CE under tag
> [computer-networks] is probably a better option.

Remember:

**Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment.**

ARQ and other academic protocols with no standard are off-topic because there is no real-world use in a business network.

Asking theoretical questions about protocols is for real protocols (ethernet, IP, TCP, UDP, etc.) used in a professionally managed network, but there is no standard for academic protocols, so the theory can be whatever an instructor claims, and they are certainly not used in a business network.

If you think a question should be asked on a different SE site, then you should add a comment recommending the SE site to the OP.

Comment: great, but `Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here` is not quite the case, is it?

Comment: Also, a textbook is not an authoritative reference standard.

Comment: @Effie, you seem to be confusing close reasons and comments. Anyone, including you, can comment, and anyone with sufficient reputation can vote to close for one of the close reasons, but they are not the same thing. If you disagree with a comment, you are free to post your own comment, and if you have sufficient reputation you can vote to reopen a question that you think is closed in error. One has nothing to do with the other.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with @Effie. While such questions are almost universally off-topic, they are so because of their academic nature. *Stop-and-Wait*, *Go-Back-N*, and *Selective-Repeat* are all academic topics. And the questions I've seen here all grew out of academic confusion. To be on-topic, one would have to be asking about something being actively used in real world networks.

TFTP would be an example of stop-and-wait. But it's also "above Layer-4". :-)

TCP, in the 70's, was a stop-and-wait system. It became a GBN with windowing and delayed ACK. But today, most implementations buffer out-of-order traffic unlike the academic defintions of GBN (where out-of-order is discarded.) The buffering mechanism is much more like SR, but SR uses individual ack's.